# Volley execute multiple times but should be 1 time only

Tags: java, android, http, request, android-volley

I use volley request inside progressbar when progress value == 100 then execute volley request to the server. Its Send request but So many time But Why?

Here is my code

```
if(progressBar.getProgress() == 100){

                        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, response -> {
                                    try {

                                        String message = response.getString("message");
                                        System.out.println(message);

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }, error -> {
                                    error.printStackTrace();
                                });

                        Volley.newRequestQueue(Attendance.this).add(jsonRequest);
                        jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(1000, -1,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        CheckInBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
```

Error Is there :

```
W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:162)
W/System.err:     at             
com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:162)
W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
I/System.out: Done For Today
E/BLASTBufferQueue: BLASTBufferItemConsumer::onDisconnect()
```

How can I solve it , Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Where is that code being called from? There could be a million reasons why the request is timing out. Did you double check your device's network connection?

Comment: how can I set it only 2 times max retries